# Spring Unit Testing on EHCache

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, ehcache

I have annotated

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "file:WebContent/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml" })

<!-- Start of  EhCache -->
    <cache:annotation-driven />
    <context:component-scan base-package="caching" />
    <bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager" p:cacheManager-ref="ehcache"/>
    <bean id="ehcache" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean" 
     p:configLocation="/WEB-INF/ehcache.xml"  
     p:shared="true"/> 
    <!-- End of EhCache -->
```

it keeps saying ehcache.xml was not found... but on normal server it can be found. may I know what is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly both you spring config and ehcache config are in same directory. So it seems you could use `p:configLocation="ehcache.xml"`